# Returning the most similar bit signature from a prefix tree in python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, trie

I never coded with python before (I'm a java programmer) and I'm looking at code that says it returns the most similar bit signature/vector in a prefix tree. The signature could be for example like this "1001". Can someone please explain to me how the code works? How does it iterate over the prefix tree in order to find the most similar/closest signature to a query signature in the tree? Similarity is based on hamming distance.

Here's the code:

```
class SignatureTrie:
    @staticmethod
    def getNearestSignatureKey(trie, signature):
        digitReplacement = {'0': '1', '1': '0'}
        targetKey, iteratingKey = signature.to01(), ''
        for i in range(len(targetKey)):
            iteratingKey+=targetKey[i]
            if not trie.has_prefix(iteratingKey): iteratingKey=iteratingKey[:-1]+digitReplacement[targetKey[i]]
        return iteratingKey
```

Here's the source file:
https://github.com/kykamath/streaming_lsh/blob/master/streaming_lsh/classes.py

Edit:

I will give an example of what "I'm" expecting the code to do. I don't know if the code actually does that or how it's doing so. That's why I'm asking for an interpretation of the code, especially traversing the prefix tree.

Suppose I have the following prefix tree that contain three strings/signatures:
s1 = 1110
s2 = 1100
s3 = 1001

[image]

Suppose I have the input signature s = 1000. Now I want to get to know which vector in the prefix/trie is the most similar to the input vector s. Since s3 have the least hamming distance (1), I'm expecting the code to return the vector s3.

What I need is someone to explain to me if the code is doing what I'm expecting it to do and if so, how it's getting the most similar signature i.e. how it's traversing the tree.

If the code is not doing what I'm expecting, can someone please explain what it does giving the example I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you posted does *not* do any of the Trie search. At all.

The function you are looking at permutes the given signature key (a string of zeros and ones) to find the *nearest* match; if no matches starting with the first character of the signature are found, it looks for items with the inverse value instead.

For your sample data, if you were to look for the signature `1101`, there are no exact matches. But the `trie` prefix search will return results for a search for `1`, for `11`, and for `110`. The search for `1101` fails, so `digitReplacement` is used to replace the last `1` with a `0`, which does match, so `1100` is the result of `getNearestSignatureKey()` function..

To find matches, prefix matching is delegated to the `trie` object. This datatype is taken from the [Biopython project](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page), and is coded [entirely in C](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/trie.c); if you are so inclined, study the [`Trie_has_prefix` function](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/trie.c#L445) to see how that type searches for matching prefixes.

Documentation on that data type is sparse; the best we have is [this autogenerated module page](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.trie-module.html):

> This module implements a trie data structure.  This allows an O(M)
>   lookup of a string in a dictionary, where M is the length of the
>   string.  It also supports approximate matches.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SignatureTrie:

    @staticmethod
    def getNearestSignatureKey(trie, signature):

        digitReplacement = {'0': '1', '1': '0'}
        targetKey = signature.to01() # string with 0 and 1
        iteratingKey = '' # empty string

        for i in range(len(targetKey)): # loop through targetKey string (i being an index)
            iteratingKey += targetKey[i] # append char at position i
            if not trie.has_prefix(iteratingKey): # if iteratingKey is not the trie
                # flip last digit (0 if 1, 1 if 0) of iteratingKey
                iteratingKey = iteratingKey[:-1]+digitReplacement[targetKey[i]]

        return iteratingKey
```

Comment: can you *please* give an example for this? because I don't understand the idea behind the flipping. I wish if you can just provide an example with a signature like "10010" and a prefix tree.

Comment: I don't understand your input vs expected output. I can only tell you what the code does.